Problems adding Fancy box to Arctic map (polar plot)
I am trying to plot a polar map on python with the zebra border line marking the longitudes. I'm using patches to generate this fancy box but it throws an error because the patch overlaps. I tried using a longitud vector with finishing at minus 1 degree and it does the plot but it doesnt look good. Does anione know how to solve it?
This is the code I'm using:
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.path as mpath
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import numpy as np

# Latitude-longitude projection
noProj = ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=0)
# Map projection
myProj = ccrs.Orthographic(central_latitude=90)
myProj._threshold = myProj._threshold / 30.  # Higher precision

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 12))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=myProj)

# Border lines at the limit
# Bottom edge segment
long_edges = np.linspace(-180, 180) 
lati_edges = np.ones(len(long_edges)) * 60
[ax_hdl] = ax.plot(long_edges, 
                   lati_edges,
                   color='black', linewidth=0.5,
                   transform=noProj)

# Transforming the path in data coordinates
tx_path = ax_hdl._get_transformed_path()
path_in_data_coords, _ = tx_path.get_transformed_path_and_affine()
polygon1s = mpath.Path(path_in_data_coords.vertices)

# Adjust vcode to the number of vertices in path_in_data_coords
vcode = np.tile([1, 2], int(len(path_in_data_coords.vertices) // 2))
if len(vcode) < len(path_in_data_coords.vertices):
    vcode = np.append(vcode, 1)
polygon1v = mpath.Path(path_in_data_coords.vertices, vcode)

# Set the graph boundary to the polygon's shape
ax.set_boundary(polygon1s)  # Masks the unwanted part of the graph

# Creating the "zebra-border" pattern
# Lower layer: thicker solid black line
# Upper layer: thinner dashed white line
patch1s = patches.PathPatch(polygon1s, facecolor='none', ec="black", lw=7, zorder=100)
patch1v = patches.PathPatch(polygon1v, facecolor='none', ec="white", lw=6, zorder=101, linestyle="--")
ax.add_patch(patch1s)
ax.add_patch(patch1v)

# Add features and labels
ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True, x_inline=False, y_inline=False)
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.OCEAN, linewidth=.3, color='lightblue')
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.LAND, zorder=1, edgecolor='black')

# Graph title
ax.title.set_text("Map with Zebra Border Line")
plt.show()

Tis is the error I get:
  File ~\.conda\envs\py3par\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py:343 in __call__
    return printer(obj)

  File ~\.conda\envs\py3par\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py:170 in print_figure
    fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)

  File ~\.conda\envs\py3par\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py:2175 in print_figure
    self.figure.draw(renderer)

  File ~\.conda\envs\py3par\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py:95 in draw_wrapper
    result = draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)

  File ~\.conda\envs\py3par\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py:72 in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer)

  File ~\.conda\envs\py3par\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py:3162 in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(

  File ~\.conda\envs\py3par\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py:132 in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)

  File ~\.conda\envs\py3par\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py:72 in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer)

  File ~\.conda\envs\py3par\Lib\site-packages\cartopy\mpl\geoaxes.py:520 in draw
    self._draw_preprocess(renderer)

  File ~\.conda\envs\py3par\Lib\site-packages\cartopy\mpl\geoaxes.py:495 in _draw_preprocess
    gl._draw_gridliner(renderer=renderer)

  File ~\.conda\envs\py3par\Lib\site-packages\cartopy\mpl\gridliner.py:807 in _draw_gridliner
    intersection = line.intersection(map_boundary)

  File ~\.conda\envs\py3par\Lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\base.py:599 in intersection
    return shapely.intersection(self, other, grid_size=grid_size)

  File ~\.conda\envs\py3par\Lib\site-packages\shapely\decorators.py:77 in wrapped
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File ~\.conda\envs\py3par\Lib\site-packages\shapely\set_operations.py:131 in intersection
    return lib.intersection(a, b, **kwargs)

GEOSException: TopologyException: Input geom 1 is invalid: Self-intersection at or near point 590.39999999999998 1260.9696790108972 at 590.39999999999998 1260.9696790108972

<Figure size 1152x1728 with 1 Axes>

This is the kind of map I want to produce:


Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74124975/cartopy-fancy-box/74255886#74255886 help?
