# Make straight lines in frames in cartopy in python

Tags: python, maps, cartopy

I want to create a map and frame:

```
import matplotlib.colors
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, 1,subplot_kw={'projection': ccrs.Mercator()}, figsize=(7,7), gridspec_kw={'wspace': 0.2, 'hspace': 0.2})
ax1.set_extent([-50.0, 45.0, 30.0, 70.0])
ax1.coastlines('50m', color='black')
ax1.plot([-19, 40, 40, -19, -19], [35, 35, 73, 73, 35],
         color='blue', linewidth=2.5,
         transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
```

But the ouput is
[image]

If I use PlateCarree:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, 1,subplot_kw={'projection': ccrs.PlateCarree()}, figsize=(7,7), gridspec_kw={'wspace': 0.2, 'hspace': 0.2})
ax1.set_extent([-50.0, 45.0, 30.0, 70.0])
ax1.coastlines('50m', color='black')
ax1.plot([-19, 40, 40, -19, -19], [35, 35, 73, 73, 35],
         color='blue', linewidth=2.5, label='Z500')
```

then the map is not correct:
[image]

Comment: What is your real question? Hope my answer guesses it right. ;p

Comment: Hi, unfortunately no. I would like to have a square with straight lines like the second plot but the background to be the map from the first plot. Does it make sense?

Comment: Check my answer again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `threshold` value is too large. You must set it smaller to get more smooth curve.

```
import matplotlib.colors
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

use_proj = ccrs.Mercator()
use_proj._threshold /= 20.

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, 1,subplot_kw={'projection': use_proj}, figsize=(7,7), gridspec_kw={'wspace': 0.2, 'hspace': 0.2})
ax1.set_extent([-50.0, 45.0, 30.0, 70.0])
ax1.coastlines('50m', color='black')
ax1.plot([-19, 40, 40, -19, -19], [35, 35, 73, 73, 35],
         color='blue', linewidth=2.5,
         transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
```

[image: merc]

See other examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73951145/cartopy-figure-for-high-latitude-with-edges-parallel-to-latitude-and-longitude/74189650?noredirect=1#comment131047106_74189650)

**Edit**
Replace the snippet code

```
transform=ccrs.Geodetic()
```

with

```
transform=ccrs.PlateCarree()
```

after rerun, the output will be

[image: merc2]

Comment: Hi, unfortunately that is not my question. I would like to have a square with straight lines like the second plot but the background to be the map from the first plot. Does it make sense?