# Hide right-side axis (latitude) labels for high-latitude non-rectangular projection in Cartopy

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, axis-labels, cartopy

I am trying to hide the right-side labels (aka latitude) in this Cartopy map using `right_labels = False` but only works for some values. However, the top/bottom labels can be hidden using `top_labels = False` and `bottom_label=False`.

To reproduce:

```
 import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import cartopy.crs as ccrs
    import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
    import matplotlib.path as mpath
    import cartopy.feature as cf

    """
    Plot Alaska
    """

    # Map View Using Cartopy
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))

    xmin=-163
    xmax=-120
    ymin=50
    ymax=71

    proj = ccrs.LambertConformal(central_longitude=(xmin+xmax)/2, central_latitude=(ymin+ymax)/2)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=proj)
    n = 20
    aoi = mpath.Path(
        list(zip(np.linspace(xmin, xmax, n), np.full(n, ymax))) + \
        list(zip(np.full(n, xmax), np.linspace(ymax, ymin, n))) + \
        list(zip(np.linspace(xmax, xmin, n), np.full(n, ymin))) + \
        list(zip(np.full(n, xmin), np.linspace(ymin, ymax, n)))
    )
    ax.set_boundary(aoi, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

    # Plot Ocean Borders
    ocean = cf.NaturalEarthFeature('physical', 'ocean', scale='50m', edgecolor='k', facecolor='lightblue', lw=1,
                                   linestyle='-')
    ax.add_feature(ocean)
    # Colored Land Background
    land = cf.NaturalEarthFeature('physical', 'land', scale='50m', facecolor='snow', lw=1, linestyle='--')
    ax.add_feature(land)

    ax.set_extent([xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    # Set gridlines to variable so you can manipulate them
    gl = ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True, crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), x_inline=False, y_inline=False)
    gl.xlocator = mticker.FixedLocator([-160, -150, -140, -130, -120])
    gl.ylocator = mticker.FixedLocator([50, 55, 60, 65, 70])
    gl.top_labels = False
    gl.right_labels = False

    plt.show()
```

And this is what I obtain:

[image: funky axes Alaska]

I have a suspicion it has to do with using `ax.set_boundary()` to make the map but after looking online I couldn't find anything except this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/1722) that mentions the issue but it is closed so I suppose they fixed it. I am using Cartopy version 0.21.1.

The question arose from looking into another SO question: [Cartopy labels not appearing for high-latitude non-rectangular projection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75586978/cartopy-labels-not-appearing-for-high-latitude-non-rectangular-projection) (all code credits to [@kbiegseismic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11232846/kbiegseismic)).

Comment: The use of `ax.set_boundary()` can disrupt other processes including `ax.gridlines()` in this case. Gridlines feature is rather new in Cartopy, will not work in many situations. One can use some workarounds to get the expected results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it is obvious that `ax.set_boundary()` confuses the process within `.gridlines()`, especially, when it needs to hide some of the y-labels in this particular case. Consequently, some of the labels' visibility are set falsely.

We will need to wait for next version of Cartopy to see better `gridlines()` funtioning. If you need a workaround, you can try the code snippets below. Just place it towards the end of existing code.

```
# Generate the plot to enable access to the labels' attributes
plt.draw()

# Iterate for the y-labels
# The right labels have x coordinates > 0
# The left labels < 0
for ea in gl.ylabel_artists:
    right_label = ea.get_position()[0] > 0
    # print(ea, ea.get_position()[0], ea.get_visible())
    if right_label:
        ea.set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

[image: no-r-labels]

If you modify the map boundaries to have small extra buffer like these:-

```
pg = 0.006
#xmin=-163 -pg
xmax=-120 +pg
ymin=50 -pg
#ymax=71 +pg
```

the final plot will include the missing labels at 120°W longitude and 50°N latitude.

[image: plot2]